# Stacked Wear notification shown on phone too

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have 1 summary-notification and serveral stacked notifications.
For some reason the stacked notifications are not only shown on the
Andrid Wear device but also on the phone.
According to the documentation
[Stacking Notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)
they should only display on the watch.
NotificationBuilder.setGroup is, of cause, set to the same value and only the summary has .setSummary(true).

Details:
http://marcuswolschon.blogspot.de/2015/05/implementing-k9-mail-wear-support.html

Code:
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/73ec00b43db81038805999f5642961ae9005d6bc/k9mail/src/main/java/com/fsck/k9/controller/MessagingController.java#L4941

Comment: why did comment out builder.setLocalOnly(true);?

Comment: Because the summary notification makes sense on the watch.

Comment: There is an issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=130689 stacked notifications are shown on phone too when summary notifcication has MAX_PRIORITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **NotificationManager** with **NotificationManagerCompat**

Use **NotificationManager**

```
private void send() {
    Notification notification1 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("News1")
                    .setGroup("News")
                    .setContentText("Text")
                    .build();

    Notification notification2 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("News2")
                    .setGroup("News")
                    .setContentText("Text2")
                    .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1 , notification1);
    notificationManager.notify(2 , notification2);

    Notification Summary = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("2 new News")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Text2")
            .setGroup("News")
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(-1 , Summary);
}
```

[image]

Use **NotificationManagerCompat**

```
private void send() {
    Notification notification1 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("News1")
                    .setGroup("News")
                    .setContentText("Text")
                    .build();

    Notification notification2 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("News2")
                    .setGroup("News")
                    .setContentText("Text2")
                    .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    notificationManager.notify(1 , notification1);
    notificationManager.notify(2 , notification2);

    Notification Summary = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("2 new News")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Text2")
            .setGroup("News")
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(-1 , Summary);
}
```

[image]